# SQLite3 seems to be ignoring ORDER BY ASC / DESC

Tags: sqlite

I have a database of sports games which includes the date of these these games in the format DD/MM/YYYY (not good I know) and I'm running the command:

```
SELECT InningsDate FROM Test WHERE InningsPlayer="Player Name" ORDER BY date(InningsDate) DESC
```

to sort by date of the innings which does sort the database, however it ignores the DESC at the end and will always show the data in the same order regardless of it I put ASC / DESC / nothing at the end.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format `DD/MM/YYYY` is not comparable and you should not use it in SQLite which does not support formatting for dates that don't have the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

A solution for your case would be:

```
ORDER BY substr(InningsDate, -4) || substr(InningsDate, 4, 2) || substr(InningsDate, 1, 2) DESC
```

but as a permanent solution consider changing the format of the dates:

```
UPDATE Test 
SET InningsDate = 
      substr(InningsDate, -4) || '-' ||
      substr(InningsDate, 4, 2) || '-' ||
      substr(InningsDate, 1, 2)
```

Comment: This has correctly sorted my code in decreasing order thank you! However I'm still confused how "ORDER BY date(InningsDate) DESC" does correctly sort the dates but won't sort them in descending order?

Comment: I hope you used my latest edited code as I had a typo. If you get correct results in ascending order this is just coincidental and depends on your data.